# Creating a startup service for python script to run as root in Arch Linux

Tags: python, linux, root, startup

I have a python script that I want to run on start up as root. I believe that I need to add it as a service file but I don't know if it has root permission. This is how i have my service file. The python file wont run unless in root.

```
[Unit]
Description= Description here

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/script.py
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=script.service
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you use cron?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. After I removed the root check from my python script everything worked fine, i also removed the `Type=simple` part from the service file. After those two things it worked fine.

the root check part i removed was.

```
from os import getenv
user = getenv("SUDO_USER")
if user is None:
    print ("This program needs to run as root")
    exit(0)
```

and the service file now looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description= Description here

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/script.py
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=script.service
```

I still don't understand why I needed to take out the root check, program ran fine when I used `sudo python script.py`. For some reason when the script was ran with systemctl it would fail the root check.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd runs multi-user services as root, so I don't see what help do you need.

Comment: I know that the Python script run and does it's job, maybe not the best way but it does what i need it to do, is there anything in the service file that looks wrong, do you think it might be something with the ExecStart

Comment: @Nimda_R2
ExecStart is ok. If you're installed this script and it doesn't work as expected (and you haven't said so), here tips for debug. Add this to file start: `import getpass; open('/home/whoami', 'w').write(getpass.getuser())`
If file wasn't even created - then you just installed script wrong, so you have systemd-related problem.

Comment: Okay so the output for the whoami file is root but i can say that the program is not running in root because i have a section of code that checks to see if program is running in root, when i run the script through the service file it doesn't detect root. This is confusing , I know the .service is running and i know the python runs but the script doesn't run properly without root. is there something i need to add to the .service file?

Comment: Thanks i used `import getpass; open('/home/whoami', 'w').write(getpass.getuser())` to help me find where the program stopped.